# I can't compile OCILIB on ubuntu

Tags: c, oracle, ubuntu, gcc

I am trying to access Oracle database using OCILIB on Ubuntu.
 I use that on the command line:

```
gcc -DOCI_IMPORT_LINKAGE -DOCI_CHARSET_ANSI -L/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe//lib -lclntsh -I$/home/user/Desktop/ocilib-4.3.1/include -locilib test.c -o con
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
test.c:(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `OCI_Initialize'
test.c:(.text+0x39): undefined reference to `OCI_ConnectionCreate'
test.c:(.text+0x49): undefined reference to `OCI_StatementCreate'
test.c:(.text+0x5e): undefined reference to `OCI_ExecuteStmt'
test.c:(.text+0x6a): undefined reference to `OCI_GetResultset'
test.c:(.text+0x81): undefined reference to `OCI_GetString'
test.c:(.text+0x95): undefined reference to `OCI_GetInt'
test.c:(.text+0xb5): undefined reference to `OCI_FetchNext'
test.c:(.text+0xbe): undefined reference to `OCI_Cleanup'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: did you tried:  `-L$ORACLE_HOME/lib -lclntsh`?

Comment: ok, than - `$ORACLE_HOME/lib/libclntsh.so` without -L (make sure ORACLE_HOME is set)

Comment: gcc -I/usr/local/include -DOCI_IMPORT_LINKAGE -DOCI_CHARSET_ANSI -L$ORACLE_HOME/lib  -Lclntsh  -L/usr/local/lib -Locilib
 Now , I got that error again    == dd.c:(.text+0x14): undefined reference to `OCI_Initialize'
dd.c:(.text+0x33): undefined reference to `OCI_Cleanup'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: and so - `gcc -I/usr/local/include -DOCI_IMPORT_LINKAGE -DOCI_CHARSET_ANSI $ORACLE_HOME/lib/libclntsh.so test.c -o con`

Comment: /tmp/cc9v33U0.o: In function `main':
test.c:(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `OCI_Initialize'
test.c:(.text+0x39): undefined reference to `OCI_ConnectionCreate'
test.c:(.text+0x49): undefined reference to `OCI_StatementCreate'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: I think my libraries is okey .Look                                                      /home# echo $ORACLE_HOME
/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe
:/usr/local/lib$ ls
libocilib.a   libocilib.so.4      node_modules  python3.4
libocilib.la  libocilib.so.4.3.1  pkgconfig     site_ruby
libocilib.so  libocilib.so.4.3.3    I dont understand what s problem :(

Comment: do you using proc?

Comment: proc file system ?

Comment: no, pro*c - precompiler

Comment: No , I didn't use it . Also how can I solve OCILIB problem :(  Do you know what is the problem , is it about libraries or oracle. I'm new to oracle and ocılıb

Comment: it's about libs. Try something like this: `gcc -I/usr/local/include -DOCI_IMPORT_LINKAGE -DOCI_CHARSET_ANSI test.c -o con -L$ORACLE_HOME/lib -locilib`

Comment: /usr/bin/ld: warning: libclntsh.so.11.1, needed by /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../lib/libocilib.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../lib/libocilib.so: undefined reference to `OCILobTrim2'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../lib/libocilib.so: undefined reference to `OCILobIsEqual'

Comment: where you downloaded ocilib to?

Comment: Where you have install ocilib? Try to add the flag: `-L/$ORACLE_HOME/lib -lclntsh` too.

Comment: gcc -I/usr/local/include -DOCI_IMPORT_LINKAGE -DOCI_CHARSET_ANSI dd.c -o con -L$ORACLE_HOME/lib -locilib
 Now I use this o command line then I can compile it . it works thank youuu

Comment: You're welcome. It's strange, exactly the same command I have proposed yesterday - 5th comment upwards. What is the difference?

Comment: I agree with you . I dont understand . I just uninstalled oracle, but this time I installed it from the software center. Then I tried again and the program was compiled on the command line without error

Comment: Ok, than you can accept answere from @vincent Rogier, he is creator of OCILIB.

Comment: Ok thank you again :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't link against ocilib library. Add -llibocilib to your command line.

Comment: I have tried I got that error: -llibocilib  test.c -o con  
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lclntsh
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibocilib
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: @vincent Rogier why -llibocilib? I think the prefix lib added automatically by option -l ?